# Filter ip.addr with hex value

Tags: wireshark

Hello I mostly using hex format for debug my program's traffic so in wireshark I also want filter ip.addr with hex value like `ip.addr == 0x7f000001` instead of `ip.addr == 127.0.0.1` is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried it? According the the Wireshark man pages, "IPv4 addresses can be represented in either dotted decimal notation or by using the hostname". But https://www.knowledgebombs.net/blog/2012/08/01/wireshark-ipip-capture-filter.html indicates that you can do it using byte-offset notation -- something like `ip[32:4]==0x7f000001 || ip[36:4]==0x7f000001`.

Comment: @DougDeden filter box beings red when i type `ip[32:4] == 0x7f000001`

Comment: That article talks about capture filters, not display filters and the syntax is a bit different in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [wireshark-filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) man page explains the proper use of the slice operator, of particular relevance:

*A slice is always compared against either a string or a byte sequence. As a special case, when the slice is only 1 byte wide, you can compare it against a hex integer that 0xff or less (which means it fits inside one byte). This is not allowed for byte sequences greater than one byte, because then one would need to specify the endianness of the multi-byte integer. Also, this is not allowed for decimal numbers, since they would be confused with hex numbers that are already allowed as byte strings.*

The following example should work:

```
ip[12:4]==7f:00:00:01 || ip[16:4]==7f:00:00:01
```

Note the proper offsets here of 12 and 16 for the source and destination IP addresses, respectively.  The offsets are specified from the beginning of the IP header since that's where you're slicing from.